# retool their systems to ease compliance

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The proliferation of fake health certificates is exposing a logistical blind spot, as airlines rush to navigate post-pandemic travel standards and **retool their systems to ease compliance**—and spur demand. Airlines say their staff aren’t equipped to handle and police all the new health certifications needed and worry the problem will be exacerbated when some countries also start to ask for vaccination certificates.

Source: [WashingtonPost](http://https:/https://www.wsj.com/articles/fake-covid-19-certificates-hit-airlines-which-now-have-to-police-them-11618330621?mod=e2tw)

What does "retool their systems to ease compliance" mean? It seems to mean "retool their systems to ease **complaints**." A typo. I am not sure.

Comment: I suggest you look up: vaccination certificates + compliance

Comment: Airlines and passengers must **comply** with various rules and regulations. They might complain about it, but that is not the reason for updating their systems.

Comment: I find the phrase confusing too. Are they trying to ease legal issues relating to compliance (by increasing compliance), or are they easing their adherence to regulations (by decreasing compliance)?

Comment: I think it is actually a third case: They are trying to ease factors which make it hard to comply, by retooling their systems.

Comment: Airlines want to actually comply with law, not make it easier for themselves to comply. It's confusing, but I read it to mean they want their systems to make it easier for their passengers to comply with their own prerequisites for flying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, it means that the airlines are rushing to retool their systems *to make it easier to comply with* the post-pandemic travel standards (such as making sure health certifications are valid). To comply means to adhere/follow the rules.